# Extracting A Clip From An MP4 File In Linux on Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, video-editing, mp4, mencoder

I'm running KUbuntu 11.10 Linux.

I would like to extract a clip from an MP4 file.   I tried this command:

```
myCLIPrompt:~/Downloads/temp/clips$ mencoder -ss 00:43:13 -endpos 00:02:12 -oac copy -ovc copy The.Original.Video.\[VTV\].mp4 -o TheClip.mp4
```

and I got this error message:

```
MEncoder SVN-r33713-4.6.1 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team

WARNING: OUTPUT FILE FORMAT IS _AVI_. See -of help.
success: format: 0  data: 0x0 - 0x19148a83
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang und
VIDEO:  [H264]  720x404  24bpp  29.970 fps  843.8 kbps (103.0 kbyte/s)
[V] filefmt:44  fourcc:0x34363248  size:720x404  fps:29.970  ftime:=0.0334
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 143.0 kbit/9.31% (ratio: 17880->192000)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
videocodec: framecopy (720x404 24bpp fourcc=34363248)
Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it.

Exiting...
```

How do I do it the correct way?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling around my ffmpeg command should have been more like this

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile -ss StartTime -t Duration Outputfiless
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:07:38 -t 00:07:36 output.mp4
```

-ss being the time in the video to start the clip at, -t the duration of the clip. Never use more than 60 units for minutes or seconds.  For example if the duration is 6 minutes and 62 seconds write 07:02, for seven minutes and two seconds

I got on the ffmpeg-users GNUMailman email list.  I was told that the Ubuntu family of distributions uses an old, buggy, unsupported port of ffmpeg.

http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017

I was told that if I wanted ffmpeg to work on even the latest Ubuntu family distribution I would need to get the source code directly from the ffmpeg project, compile and set it up myself.

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

HTH

Steve

Comment: Just want to note: this work on the HomeBrew version of ffmpeg on Mac OS/X Mountain Lion as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use `avconv`. For example, if you'd like to extract a clip of duration 10s starting at 15s, then you'd use

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 -codec copy output.mp4
```

There are a lot more options that you can play with, like specifying the resolution, output format etc. See the man page of `avconv` for all the options.

If you happen to have `ffmpeg` you can use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: The second one worked for me.  I don't have avconv in my system.  When I Googled how to install it I saw something about having to compile it.  Does it do anything that ffmpeg doesn't to justify the trouble?

Comment: ffmpeg is now deprecated. It is not developed anymore and is there on 12.04 only for compatibility.

Comment: Good to know, I'll switch to avcconv when there is a compiled version to download.  Thanks for the good info.

Comment: No problem. Cheers mate :)

Comment: @abhshkdz **FFmpeg is not deprecated**. It is actively developed. Where did you get that info from? The Ubuntu package message is simply wrong. See here: [Bug #939863 “Warning message from ffmpeg program needs update”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/939863)

Comment: @user787832 FFmpeg is not deprecated, feel free to use it. See my comment above.

Comment: For me it wouldn't work unless I put the `-i inputfile` argument *first*, and then the `-ss -t` arguments in the middle, and then the outputfile...  SO: `avconv -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 -codec copy output.mp4`